# Delete Django queryset in a concurrency-safe way

Tags: django, django-orm

I want to delete a row with a zero quantity in a way that is concurrency-safe. It is conceivable that the row could become non-zero just before it is deleted.

The models looks something like this:

```
class Stock(models.Model):
   product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
   location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
   quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

To delete it, I am using:

```
Stock.objects.filter(product=product, quantity=0).delete()
```

I want the SQL to be:

```
DELETE FROM app_stock WHERE product=product AND quantity=0
```

But it is being optimized to:

```
DELETE FROM "app_stock" WHERE "app_stock"."id" IN (5)
```

This optimization is quite reasonable in a sense as the ID of the object to be deleted is 5 and this is more efficient. Unfortunately it is not going to be safe as the stock could be increased by another process at anytime.

I can fix this with raw SQL. I have also tried trying other queries but it is always optimized the same way.

Comment: The reason this happens is because the `on_delete` triggers are not done by the database, but by Django's ORM, so it first needs to know if it needs to delete other records.

Answer (score 0):

> This optimization is quite reasonable in a sense as the ID of the object to be deleted is 5 and this is more efficient.

**No**, this is not done for performance reasons, especially since in order to first know what the primary keys are, Django performs another query. So in order to delete, at least two queries are done.

The reason this happens is because Django itself performs the `on_delete=…` queries. It thus first needs to objects that will be removed, and if there are `ForeignKey`s etc. it will also fetch related querysets that point to these objects to perform the triggers accordingly. By doing the triggers manually, it is (almost) impossible to do this in a single query.

The best chance is probably to wrap these in *transactions* such that the eventual removal is done atomically: it either succeeds completely, or not at all.